# Trying to create div > ul with jquery append

Tags: jquery, append

This snippet of code creates a ul outside of the .tile div, but I need to be inside.

```
$(container).append(
 '<div class="tile" />' + '<ul class="layer"></ul>' + '</div>'
);

RESULT:              
<div class="tile"></div>
<ul class="layer"></ul>

TRYING TO GET:
<div class="tile">
 <ul class="layer"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with class "title" is using a self-closing tag `<div ... />`

Do this instead

```
$(container).append(
 '<div class="tile">' + '<ul class="layer"></ul>' + '</div>'
);
```

Or do something like this

```
var content = $('<div>')
    .addClass('title')
    .append(
        $('<ul>').addClass('layer')
    );
$(container).append(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append an element by:

```
$('container').append($("div").addClass("tile").append($('ul').addClass("layer")));
```

You are creating and adding an element, so know that you can do like:

```
var tile = $("div")
              .addClass("tile")
              .append(
                  $('ul')
                  .addClass("layer")
                  .append($("li").text("first in list"))
                  .append($("li").text("second in list"))
              );
$('container').append(tile);
```

[See more examples in doc file](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: `$('.title')` is not present in the DOM. It has to be created first.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the `.title` element with a slash. This is "shorthand" to tell HTML you want to instantly close the element once it's created. Try the following instead.

```
'<div class="title">' + '<ul class="layer"></ul>' + '</div>'
```

Interesting thing I found while seeking the answer to this question is that `document.write` doesn't suffer from this behaviour, so maybe it's something with how jQuery parses the HTML vs your browser/interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the result is:

```
$(container).append('<div class="tile" />').children('.tile').append('<ul class="layer"/>');
```

Or you may use:

```
$(container).append(function(index, html) {
    return $('<div class="tile" />').append('<ul class="layer"/>');
});
```

Or:

```
var eleToAppend = $('<div class="tile" />').append('<ul class="layer"/>');
$(container).append(eleToAppend);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very Simple**

try below code once :-

```
$(container).append('<div class="tile"><ul class="layer"></ul></div>');
```